# Display a text field as phone number in VF page with Custom controller

Tags: visualforce

I am using custom controller for my VF page, and have created a text field that takes phone number. I would like to set this field to be formatted as a phone field, but since I am using a custom controller, I can not inherit out of the box functionality. I did do some research, but could not identify a clear solution other than that most likely I need to use Java.

```
<label for="phone">Phone Number * </label>
<apex:inputText id="phone" value="{!phone}" styleClass="{!IF(validPhone,'form-control','form-control error')}" html-placeholder="999-888-7777" />
<apex:outputText rendered="{!NOT(validPhone)}"><span class="error">Please enter a Phone Number</span></apex:outputText>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you read the [Visualforce Developer Guide](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_compref_input.htm) you might notice that under the apex:input Attributes you can use HTML5 type

> tel

to generate an `<input>` element for your use case.

Additionally, to validate a certain format/length, you can use Javascript on the client side.

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_compref_input.htm